# How to update my Windows Service automatically in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, clickonce, auto-update

I release several modifications a week for my Windows Services and my users have to update it manually. I was think in rolling my own auto-update component, but I heard of ClickOnce, which seems to suit only Windows Forms and not Windows Services. Is there any similar solution for my case?

And if I should develop this feature myself, should I:

1. Stop the service, replace the files, start the service?

or

2. Uninstall and Install the new version?

for both options I think I will need admin rights, which require user intervention, so it's not automatic at all, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the service simply be a shell.  Every so often (once a day?) have the service check for a new version by querying a web server.  If a new version exists, have it unload the actual assembly which performs the work, download and save the new assembly, then kick itself off again.